# Is it possible to properly solder SMA connectors to flexible coax (RG400)?

Tags: rf, connector, coax

It looks like only crimp connectors are widely available for flexible double-shielded coax cable like RG400.

There is also wide availability of solder connectors for semi-rigid cable like RG402 (but it's single-shielded).

I personally like soldered connections, but is it even possible to have soldered SMA properly working on flexible cable like RG400? It is clear that I cannot simply use RG402 connector with RG400 cable due to diameter mismatch.

Is there any double-shielded semi-rigid coax cables compatible with RG402 soldered connectors?

Comment: Is it possible? I wouldn’t say its impossible. Crimp is generally the better solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That depends on what you mean by "properly".

Good quality SMA connectors are generally 'solder - crimp', you can either solder or crimp the center pin but the shield is always crimped.

There's really no reason to want to solder the shield, it's a pain to do, and the heat of soldering is likely to melt the insulation. Also, soldering the fine braid makes it less flexible and prone to breaking where the soldered part meets the non-soldered part.

I've crimped a lot of connectors of various types. Done correctly with the appropriate crimp tool it works very well. About the only time I see failures is when someone does it wrong, or in a cable that gets flexed a lot, such as a jumper used on test equipment, and there a soldered one would fail just as fast if not faster than a crimped one.